# How to correctly spawn a subprocess with Tkinter and exit?

Tags: python, tkinter, popen

I'm trying to write a simple python(3.7) program using Tkinter which, upon clicking a button, will spawn a process and terminate the Python script. The spawned process should not be killed. The following code implements this:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import time

def execute_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True,
            universal_newlines = True)

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.button_gimp = Button(self.frame, text = "GIMP", command = self.gimp)
        self.button_gimp.pack(side = LEFT)

    def gimp(self):
        execute_command("gimp")
        self.frame.quit()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
time.sleep(5)
```

However, without the sleep() at the end, the process (in this case GIMP), is killed before it gets to open. Any ideas of what is going on here? I know Popen is asynchronous, but once it returns, the process should be guaranteed to be spawned, even if python terminates, shouldn't it? It even has its own PID, which can be printed.

Update::

Following a lead from John Anderson, I found out that 
`stdout = subprocess.PIPE` is the culprit. I'd appreciate any insights as to why, since this is merely telling Popen to capture the output of the process.

Comment: Investigate `os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, scriptFileName, scriptFileName)`

Comment: @JohnAnderson Following your hint made me find the answer (which raises another question), I will update the original post